# Adding fractions (to find an equal) without known denominator

Tags: fractions

The question is "Find $v$":

$$\frac {1}{20}=\frac {1}{30}+\frac {1}{v}$$

I have no idea what I'm really doing so if someone could explain in a somewhat easy-to-understand way I'd really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:
$$
\dfrac{1}{v}=\dfrac{1}{20}-\dfrac{1}{30}
$$
then find the inverse of $\dfrac{1}{v}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\frac{1}{20}=\frac{1}{30}+\frac{1}{v}\\
\frac{1}{20}=\frac{v+30}{30v}\\
v+30=\frac{30v}{20}\\
v+30=\frac{3v}{2}\\
30=\frac{v}{2}\\
v=60
$$

Answer (score 1):

If you multiply both sides of the equation by $v$ you will no longer
have an "unknown denominator":

\begin{align}
\frac {1}{20} &= \frac {1}{30} + \frac {1}{v} \\
\left(\frac {1}{20}\right) v &= \left(\frac {1}{30} + \frac {1}{v} \right) v\\
\frac {1}{20} v &= \frac {1}{30} v + 1 
\end{align}

Now this is in a form you should already know how to solve.

My first thought actually was to do it according to the answer by
Emilio Novati (which I think is the answer you should accept)
but sometimes if you don't see the "nicest" way to solve something,
just trying different things will get you to a point where you
know how to continue.
The answer by Oussama Boussif is also valid: again, not the neatest solution,
but if you just follow through with it, it will work out eventually.